# Android-quick start app with google drive is not working

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I am trying to upload an image using quick start tutorial to google drive initially my app  starts and asks to choose account but when I select an account it keeps asking again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the code, no account name is passed. Try setting [`useDefaultAccount()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#useDefaultAccount()) method which will specify that the default account should be used when connecting to services. Otherwise, use  [`clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect()) method if you prefer setting up multiple accounts. This method will clear the account selected and will prompt the user to pick an account before reconnecting.

See [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) for more information regarding `sign_in`.

In addition to that, see also [installation and configuration of the Google Play services SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started#install_and_configure_the_google_play_services_sdk) regarding creation of credentials.

If you haven't done so, check credentials created for your project. Here are the steps:

> 1. Open the [Credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) in the API Console.
> 2. Follow these steps if your application needs to submit authorized
>      requests:
>
>    a. Click **Create credentials > OAuth client ID**.
>
>    b. Select **Android**.
>
>    c. In the **Package name** field, enter your Android app's [package name](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package).
>
>    d. Paste the SHA1 fingerprint into the form where requested.
>
>    e. Click **Create**.
>
>    Otherwise, follow the steps below, which are for applications that only need to make unauthorized API calls:
>
>    a. Click **Create credentials > API key**.
>
>    b. Select **Android key**.
>
>    c. Paste the SHA1 fingerprint into the form where requested.
>
>    d. Type your Android app's [package name](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) into the form where requested.
>      e. Click **Create**.